# Set image src to another image jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with some images, and when I clicked on those images I want another div to open with that Image that I clicked.

**JS**

```
$('.examples img').click(function() {
    var loc = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#image-zoom').attr("src",loc);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container examples"  >
    <div id="image-zoom">
        <img class="img-thumbnail zoom" src="" alt="dental">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <img id="zoom" class="img-thumbnail zoom" src="images/01.png" alt="dental">
            <img class="img-thumbnail zoom" src="images/02.png" alt="dental">
            <img class="img-thumbnail zoom" src="images/03.png" alt="dental">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <img class="img-thumbnail zoom" src="images/04.png" alt="dental">
            <img class="img-thumbnail zoom" src="images/05.png" alt="dental">
            <img class="img-thumbnail zoom" src="images/06.png" alt="dental">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to Hide the div its working, so I have error in syntax I think

Comment: anything in console??

Comment: `#image-zoom'` is not an `img` tag so it can't have a `src` attribute

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Change the `src` of the image, not of the div:

```
$('#image-zoom img').attr("src",loc);
```

Answer (score 4):

change  line 3 to reference the image instead of its container:

```
$('#image-zoom img').attr("src",loc);
```

Answer (score 0):

`#image-zoom` is an id for a div tag, which doesn't have a `src` attribute. So in order to change the image you've to traverse to `img`:

```
$('#image-zoom img').attr("src",loc);
```