# Set multiple link href to a specific link jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

according to this: [Set image src to another image jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794641/set-image-src-to-another-image-jquery) it says you can do that function, can it be done to links simialrly ?

```
<div id="infolink"><a href="#">See this page</a></div>

<div class="box1"><a href="www.example.com"></a></div>
<div class="box1"><a href="www.example2.com"></a></div>
```

Yes, so there are two links in two boxes with same `class` but with different links, when you click any of these boxes, the link in that box will go to the `#infobox` link

### Update

will this work :

```
 $('.box1 ').click(function() {
var get = $('.box1 a').attr('href');
$('#infolink a').attr('href', get);}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **prevent the default action of the click** event on other two anchor tags with

```
e.preventDefault();
```

and then **redirect the user to location** specified by anchor tag withing `<div>` with `id='infolink'` by

```
location.href  = $("#infolink > a")[0].href
```

Javascript:

```
  $(".box1 > a").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href  = $("#infolink > a")[0].href
  })
```

Here the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3sWIXHIlnr9zi44K7XZi?p=preview)

OR

You may simply **change their `href` altogether**

```
$(function(){

  var ele = $(".box1");

  ele.each(function(){
     $(this).children('a')[0].href = $("#infolink > a")[0].href
   })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood this is what you need.

```
$(".box1").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); // Get url from clicked href
    $("#infolink").find("a").attr("href", url); // set it to infolink href
    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent form submission
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$( ".box1 a" ).click(function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var get = $(this).attr('href');
 $("#infolink a").attr('href', get)
});
```