# Change the source of the image inside the <td> that has alt=“selected”. Image has no ID tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Trying to change the source of an image with JavaScript or jQuery.  Its not possible for us to change the source of the file or to replace the image itself.  The table is created programmatically.

Problem is that the image or the `<td>` that contains the image inside as no ID tags.  The only thing that the `<td>` has is the `alt=”selected”` tag.  I want to change the source of the image inside the `<td>` that has its `alt=“selected”`.

this is my handicap try that didn’t work.

HTML :

```
<td class="ms-vb2">
   <img border="0" align="absmiddle" style="cursor: hand" src="/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif" alt="Selected">
</td>
```

JQUERY :

```
$("img[alt='selected']").src( "http://myimage.png" );
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please provide your code so that we can help

Comment: Try $("img[alt='selected']").css('background', 'url: ('http://myimage.png') no-repeat')

Comment: <td class="ms-vb2"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" style="cursor: hand" src="/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif" alt="Selected"></td>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set image src to another image jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794641/set-image-src-to-another-image-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$( "img[alt='selected']" ).attr('src',"http://myimage.png" );
```

Comment: Thank you Mostafa.  It worked! 

Thank you Keith but yours wasn't working.

Thank you Lucas for extra input!